# customize listview can't show all data, android studio

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, crud

I'm thinking how to show data at the customize listview page. can you guys help me to find out where is the mistakes?

here is the assignment

```
Model txn;
        public SQLiteHelper mSQLiteHelper;
        ListView mListView;
        ArrayList<Model> mList;
        RecordListAdapter mAdapter = null;
```

this is the initialization

```
 mListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new RecordListAdapter(this, R.layout.row, mList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mSQLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this);
        mList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is my page which showing all data, I put a debugger to debug. It can get my all data which have 15 columns, But it can't show at the listview page. is there any mistake at this code?

```
try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = mSQLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Table1", null);
            mList.clear();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                txn = new Model();
                txn.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
                txn.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
                txn.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")));
                txn.setPhone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("phone")));
                mList.add(new Model());
            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (mList.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No record found...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This should work perfectly as expected.

Comment: ya. But It doesn't work. there is something wrong but don't know where. @Khemraj

Comment: mList.add(new Model());
Please check mList size, as you adding everytime new object in this so no data in mList to notify in adapter.

Comment: you have to change code from mList.add(new Model()); to mList.add(txn); please check my answer.

Comment: Okay Guys, The problem is It skips at the `mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener` Do you guys know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code

```
mListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

mSQLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this);
mList = new ArrayList<>();

mAdapter = new RecordListAdapter(this, R.layout.row, mList);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Data binding function code

```
try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mSQLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Table1", null);
        mList.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            txn = new Model();
            txn.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
            txn.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
            txn.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")));
            txn.setPhone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("phone")));
            mList.add(txn);
        }

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (mList.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No record found...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and I have one more suggestion, do not add listview click listener inside of your data binding function.

Comment: yes got it you have to also remove  mList = new ArrayList<>(); this line which is added after  mSQLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this);

Comment: because first you are creating Adapter using old ref. then you are creating the second instance that's not valid so please remove that line